# Vector Plot of Electric Field (Laplace's Equation)

Tags: python, math, physics, numerical-methods

I have solved Laplace's equation for a 2D square box analytically, and would like to plot the electric field vectors as a function of y and x. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ws3LIfWxfcM This is a good link to show the end equation I used. I differentiated the solution for potential to find the electric field.
The issue I am getting is that my summation loop I have set up does not converge as n increases, hence for n above 50, I am getting answers for electric field of the order of 10^100. Hence my program does not plot as the values are so large.

My summation loop has so far worked well. For instance, I plotted f(x,y) = sin(x) i^ + cos(y)j^, and compared these against a Taylor expansion of sin(x) and cos(x).
I believe the issue lies in dividing by sinh(npi). When I add this term, it quickly becomes an infinitely large number and refuses to plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

x = np.arange(-1,1,0.1)
y = np.arange(-1,1,0.1)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

a = np.zeros(len(X))
for n in range(50):
    # x component of electric field
    i = (np.cos(n*np.pi)-1)*(-np.cos(n*np.pi*X)*np.sinh(n*np.pi*Y))*1/(np.sinh(np.pi)) 
    a = np.add((i), a)

b = np.zeros(len(Y))
for n in range(50):
    # y component of electric field
    j = (np.cos(n*np.pi)-1)*(np.sin(n*np.pi*X)*np.cosh(n*np.pi*Y))*1/(np.sinh(np.pi))
    b = np.add((i), a)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# when I print a or b, it returns inf

q = ax.quiver(X, Y, a, b)

plt.show()
```

I expect the electric field vector to be very large at the 'walls'.

Comment: 1) The solution in the video divides by `sinh(n*pi)` whereas you are dividing by `sinh(pi)`. 2) The sum is over **odd** values of `n`. 3) You copied `np.add((i), a)` from the X-component loop without changing the arguments to `j, b`. I'm sure there are multiple other bugs.

Comment: What boundary conditions do you have?

Comment: (1) Um, don't link to a video, don't link to images either, if there is something you want people to know then type it into the problem statement. Making people puzzle it out is going to discourage them from helping you. (2) When you say "I expect the electric field vector to be very large at the 'walls'", do you mean actually infinite? If so maybe just stay away from the walls -- arrange your discretization so that the points are all inside, not falling on the boundaries. E.g. if 0 and 1 are giving you trouble, then instead of [0, 0.1, 0.2, ... 1], discretize as [0.05, 0.15, 0.25, ..., 0.95].

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now believe that is the issue. My electric field is infinite at the walls so therefore refuses to plot. I'm now looking at ways to fix that.